# KeyDown event: vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown to increment datefield in a form without losing focus of the field

Tags: forms, controls, ms-access-2016, onkeydown

I have a teenie little code in use vbKeyUp or Down to increment a date field (SaleDate).  How can I keep the focus in the Field SaleDate?  Currently, the UpArrow up key decrements the date one day, and changes focus to the previous field.  The DownArrow key increases the date, but moves focus to the next record.  In both cases I would like to be able to press the key one or more times to change the date by one or more days.

```
Private Sub SaleDate_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
 Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyUp
            'MsgBox "UP"
            Me.SaleDate = Me.SaleDate - 1
        Case vbKeyDown
            'MsgBox "DOWN"
            Me.SaleDate = Me.SaleDate + 1        
    End Select
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there, just:

Suppress the normal function of the key by setting KeyCode to 0:

```vb
Private Sub SaleDate_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
 Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyUp
            'MsgBox "UP"
            Me.SaleDate = Me.SaleDate - 1
            KeyCode = 0
        Case vbKeyDown
            'MsgBox "DOWN"
            Me.SaleDate = Me.SaleDate + 1
            KeyCode = 0        
    End Select
End sub
```

And set the `Form.KeyPreview` property to `True` in the design pane to make sure that your code triggers before the standard effect does, not after.

Comment: That did the job!  Thanks very much.